# How do I loop this animation indefinitely?

Tags: jquery, animation

I'm kinda new to jquery and I managed to program a small animation which fades in and fades out two pictures.

My problem now is that after it has gone round the cycle, it just stops. I need it to start from the beginning again when it reaches the end. It should just continue.

Here's the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('img.banner1').fadeOut(5000);
    $('img.banner2').delay(1000).fadeIn(5000);
    $('img.banner2').delay(1000).fadeOut(5000);
    $('img.banner1').fadeIn(5000).delay(1000);
});
```

Comment: Place the part that does the animations inside a function that calls itself when it is finished, or run the function every x milliseconds with a setInterval.

Comment: Why did this get voted down?

Comment: Recently I witness haters voting down all day long

Comment: @kidwon Me too, and a lot for new users posting their first question.  No love at all...

Answer (score 6):

This code will restart the function after the 1000ms delay after starting the final fadeIn. You might want a longer delay though since you take 5000ms to fade that banner in...

```
function animateBanners() {
    $('img.banner1').fadeOut(5000);
    $('img.banner2').delay(1000).fadeIn(5000);
    $('img.banner2').delay(1000).fadeOut(5000);
    $('img.banner1').fadeIn(5000).delay(1000).queue(animateBanners);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    animateBanners();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could move it to a function and invoke with setInterval.

```
function AnimateBanners() {
    $('img.banner1').fadeOut(5000);
    $('img.banner2').delay(1000).fadeIn(5000);
    $('img.banner2').delay(1000).fadeOut(5000);
    $('img.banner1').fadeIn(5000).delay(1000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(AnimateBanners, 10000); //Will run every 10 seconds
});
```

​