# Getting a jQuery animate function to loop indefinitely?

Tags: javascript, animation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I loop this animation indefinitely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13978348/how-do-i-loop-this-animation-indefinitely)

Could someone please show me how i could get this script to repeat or loop (as in not end the animation function and continue it forever and ever and ever).

I am very new to javascript so would be grateful if someone is able to show me what i can do to make this happen.

Thank you.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var rageImg = $('.foo');
    $(rageImg).animate({top:'+=100px'}, 1000).animate({top:'-=100px'}, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS only:

```
.foo {
  animation:sway 1s infinite alternate;
  position:relative;
}
@keyframes sway {
  from {top:0px}
  to {top:100px}
}
```

Add `-webkit` prefixes (`-webkit-animation`, `@-webkit-keyframes`) for Chrome support.

Works in IE10, Firefox 16 (add `-moz-` prefixes for Firefox 5 though 15), and Chrome 4.

<del>Since this is most likely aesthetic, not being supported is no big deal.</del>

jQuery answer:

```
$(function() {
  $('.foo').animate({top:'+=100px'},1000)
                   .animate({top:'-=100px'},1000,arguments.callee);
});
```

Comment: While not a direct answer, +1 for this alternative. (Although it is a big deal if some "aesthetic" things aren't supported ;-/)

Comment: Added a jQuery solution, since apparently providing an optimal answer is grounds for downvoting...

Comment: If I would be an ass here I'd go like.. "`arguments.callee` will fail in es5 strict, -1"

Comment: @jAndy And how would you suggest one refers to the ***anonymous*** function?

Comment: @Kolink `arugments.callee` is deprecated in ECMAScript 5th edition :( Thankfully all current browsers work with function names (in function expressions) and the applicable scope: `x = function fnName () { return fnName }` (fnName is not accessible in the outside scope).

Answer (score 3):

```
$(function loop() {
    $('.foo').animate({ top: '+=100px' }, 1000, function() {
        $(this).animate({ top: '-=100px' }, 1000, loop);
    });
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/VC3S6/

Comment: Nice. Could also be `$(loop)`.

Comment: I would +1 this, but... using jQuery when CSS can do it just fine? -1 for that. So no vote ;)

Comment: @Kolink Because as nice as it is to only target "consumer" systems, some of us still need to target IE7 (hey, no longer IE6, hurrah! hurrah!)

Answer (score 0):

```
function loop() {
    $(rageImg).animate({top:'+=100px'}, 1000).animate({top:'-=100px'}, loop);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    loop();
});
```

*Demo*: http://jsfiddle.net/JD9hN/

Comment: @JohnSimmons - Then you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @JohnSimmons Make sure to specify *how* it "didn't work" or "failed to work correctly". Include all relevant error messages and symptoms.

Comment: there was no error message, the object just didnt animate.

Comment: -1 for erroneous answer.

Comment: @Kolink: whats the error

Comment: Replace $(rageImg). with just rageImg. In your fuction and the selector will be right.

Comment: @jAndy Where is the "duration" argument for the second animation?

Comment: @Kolink: it'll use default values. Thats not an error and will work, did you really downvote that ?

Comment: Those default values probably aren't what was desired, though.

Comment: @Kolink: I'm missing the *bullshit argument* for the comment flags.